# filter products using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an app in php where I have to filter some products by category using Ajax and I don't have any idea how.

My all php code:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("config.php");


//current URL of the Page. cart_update.php redirects back to this URL
$current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Shopping Cart</title>
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Products </h1>

<!-- Products List Start -->
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, price FROM products ORDER BY id ASC");
if($results){ 
$products_item = '<ul class="products">';
//fetch results set as object and output HTML
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
$products_item .= <<<EOT

<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">
<table>
<tr>
<td> Name: {$obj->product_name}</td>
<td>Category: {$obj->product_desc}</td>
<td> Price: {$currency}{$obj->price} </td>
<td>
    <span>Color: </span>
    <select name="product_color">
    <option value="Black">Black</option>
    <option value="Silver">Silver</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <span>Quantity: </span>
    <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty" value="1" />
</td>
<td>
<div align="center"><button type="submit" class="add_to_cart">Add</button></div></td>
<input type="hidden" name="product_code" value="{$obj->product_code}" />
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="add" />
<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="{$current_url}" />

</div></div>
</form>
</table>
EOT;
}
$products_item .= '</ul>';
echo $products_item;
}
?>    
<!-- Products List End -->

<?php
if(isset($_SESSION["cart_products"]) && count($_SESSION["cart_products"])>0)
{

echo '<h3><center>Your Shopping Cart</center></h3>';
echo '<form method="post" action="cart_update.php">';
echo '<table width="30%"  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0"';
echo '<tbody>';

$total =0;
$b = 0;
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_products"] as $cart_itm)
{
    $product_name = $cart_itm["product_name"];
    $product_qty = $cart_itm["product_qty"];
    $product_price = $cart_itm["product_price"];
    $product_code = $cart_itm["product_code"];
    $product_color = $cart_itm["product_color"];
    $bg_color = ($b++%2==1) ? 'odd' : 'even'; //zebra stripe
    echo '<tr class="'.$bg_color.'">';
    echo '<td>Qty <input type="text" size="2" maxlength="2" name="product_qty['.$product_code.']" value="'.$product_qty.'" /></td>';
    echo '<td>'.$product_name.'</td>';
    echo '<td><input type="checkbox" name="remove_code[]" value="'.$product_code.'" /> Remove</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    $subtotal = ($product_price * $product_qty);
    $total = ($total + $subtotal);
}
echo '<td colspan="4">';
echo '<button type="submit">Update</button>';
echo '</td>';
echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';
echo '</h1>';
$current_url = urlencode($url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
echo '<input type="hidden" name="return_url" value="'.$current_url.'" />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';


}
?>


<div id="maindiv">

 <select id="options">
  <option value="v1">Category</option>

</select>

<table id="destinations" border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
    </tr>

</table>



</div>


</body>
</html>
```

I really can not understand how to make this filter.Can someone gives me some ideas in order to resolve this task?

Comment: i'll tell you if u sell the car wash to walter white

Comment: if you HAVE to use AJAX you will have to create your query dynamically based on user input.. a better idea for something like this is to use Datatables tho..

Comment: can you post the whole project here? nah, I'm kidding. I'm just wondering why you post such a big code snippet of HTML, for what? I'd encourage you first of all to read some tutorials on how to work with AJAX, and why. You question is too general to answer in a simple form. I'd vote to close it.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us much to go on in terms of what this "filter" is. If I assume by "filter" you mean you wish to alter your SQL query according to some user-initiated AJAX call(s) to this script, then you'll need the following:

- A POST or GET request sent via AJAX containing the database fields you wish to filter on. Note: Use some sort of alias or map instead of passing *actual* database column-names where the user can see it, that'd be a security flaw - also ensure you escape (clean-up) any user-input before it goes anywhere near your SQL queries :-)
- A `WHERE` clause to insert into your SQL query, constructed dynamically from the above POST or GET data

That's pretty much it.

**Very Rough** example:

```
$sql = "SELECT product_code, product_name, product_desc, price FROM products";
// Where $_POST['filter'] comes from an AJAX POST request in the frontend
if (!empty($_POST['filter'])) {
    $codeSql = ' ' . (!empty($_POST['code']) ? "product_code = '" . mysqli_escape_string($_POST['code']) . '" : '');
    $nameSql = ' ' . (!empty($_POST['name']) ? "product_name = '" . mysqli_escape_string($_POST['name']) . '" : '');
    $sql .= "WHERE " . $codeSql . $nameSql;
}
$sql .= " ORDER BY id ASC";

$results = $mysqli->query($sql);
```

Comment: I meant to browse some products by category.Thank you for your answer but I don't have any user input. I just have a table with the products from database, and then a new table with no value on it.(maindiv tells about it).